# Visual Studio 2010 via remote desktop on mac (running snow leopard)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, macos, debugging, remote-desktop

I have connected to my office PC via RDC on the mac (running osx 10.6). I am desperately trying to figure out how to use the f10 key to step through my code using the debugger...

Has anyone got any ideas!?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the "FN" key on your keyboard.  It toggles between the OSX custom behavior and traditional Function key behavior.

Look at the keyboard below.  The FN Key is in the group of 9 keys between the letters and the numeric keypad.
[image: Big Mac Keyboard]

Comment: may I ask if you worked on visual studio remotely using RDC on mac?

Comment: Not as regular practice. If memory serves, I had a mac available when I saw this question and gave it a shot.

Comment: I use RDC on my mac and connect to windows machine to run my opengl programs(c++). However while using RDC the win machines throws a access violation error. Have you ever come across such a problem ?

Comment: No, but wouldn't it be great if there were a site where you could ask questions like this?;-)

Comment: Trust me, I've been searching for the past 20 days. Tried about 1000 ways. None worked. But, yeah it would be nice to have such a site :D

Comment: If searching & tinkering isn't working, why don't *ask* a question?  The depth of knowledge here has very few bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure there's an option under System Preferences/Keyboard to use the Fn keys as standard function keys.